# Is there a way to know in the ServletContextListener what has changed in the Web Application?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servletcontextlistener

Is there a way to know, in the ServletContextListener, which file in the web application has been changed that caused the context to reload?
is it a JSP file? can i find out which .class file has been changed?

Comment: Why? What are you going to do about it in the `ServletContextListener` that you can't get from the container log files?

Comment: EJP, currently there's some long processing code done at both contextDestroyed and contextInitialized. This code does not need to run if for example a JSP file has been changed, and also this code is run for all classes. if it knew which classes have changed it could only do it for those classes

Answer (score 0):

you could implement a file change listener,

```
public class FileMonitor
{
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileMonitor.class);
    private static final FileMonitor instance = new FileMonitor();
    private Timer timer;
    private Map timerEntries;

private FileMonitor() {
    this.timerEntries = new HashMap();
    this.timer = new Timer(true);
}

public static FileMonitor getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

/**
 * Add a file to the monitor
 * 
 * @param listener The file listener
 * @param filename The filename to watch
 * @param period The watch interval.
 */
public void addFileChangeListener(FileChangeListener listener, 
    String filename, long period) {
    this.removeFileChangeListener(filename);

    logger.info("Watching " + filename);

    FileMonitorTask task = new FileMonitorTask(listener, filename);

    this.timerEntries.put(filename, task);
    this.timer.schedule(task, period, period);
}

/**
 * Stop watching a file
 * 
 * @param listener The file listener
 * @param filename The filename to keep watch
 */
public void removeFileChangeListener(String filename) {
    FileMonitorTask task = (FileMonitorTask)this.timerEntries.remove(filename);

    if (task != null) {
        task.cancel();
    }
}

private static class FileMonitorTask extends TimerTask {
    private FileChangeListener listener;
    private String filename;
    private File monitoredFile;
    private long lastModified;

    public FileMonitorTask(FileChangeListener listener, String filename) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.filename = filename;

        this.monitoredFile = new File(filename);
        if (!this.monitoredFile.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        this.lastModified = this.monitoredFile.lastModified();
    }

    public void run() {
        long latestChange = this.monitoredFile.lastModified();
        if (this.lastModified != latestChange) {
            this.lastModified = latestChange;

            this.listener.fileChanged(this.filename);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Code is not mine and i can't find the author atm i will update as soon as i find out.

Comment: In other words duplicating what the container is already doing, so doubling the overhead.